# read_line_to_codes Prolog swipl strange behaviour

Tags: input, prolog

I want to read user name and display it with capital letter, i made something like that.

```
notice:-
    write('Hi whats ur name?'), nl,
    read_line_to_codes(user_input,Codes1),
    capitalize(Codes1,Codes2)
    ->
    atom_codes(Name,Codes2),
    write(Name).

capitalize([],[]).
capitalize([H1|T], [H2|T]):-
    code_type(H2, to_upper(H1)).
```

I dont understand the problem it seems, like user_input is empy and without any reading executes.

Whats even stranger this one seems to work well...

```
notice:-
    write('Hi whats ur name?'), nl,
    read(Name),
    write(Name).
```

[This image describes problem well...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDtfP.png)

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you running this code to test it?

The first version of your code works fine for me in the SWI-Prolog shell:

```
?- notice.
Hi whats ur name?
|: isabelle
Isabelle
true.
```

It also works fine when started as a "standalone" program:

```
$ swipl -s foo.pl -q -t notice
Hi whats ur name?
|: isabelle
Isabelle
```

(Although you should add a newline after the output.)

Comment: Thats a little simplier version of mine real notice. 

menu:-
        write('Choose ur path'), nl,
        read(X), nl,
        menul(X).

    menul(1):-
        start.

start:-
    notice.

Comment: The problem is still right there maybe its connected with earlier choosing path?

Comment: `read/1` is **very very different** from `read_line_to_codes/2`. Do **not** use `read/1` if you don't understand how to use it. (It wants to read a term terminated by a period. That's almost certainly not what you want.) Remove `read/1` from your question, rewrite it in terms of `read_line_to_codes/2`, and **put your actual code into your question**, since otherwise we cannot test it.